# Proper way to deal with cursor [sqlite/Python]?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have question regarding proper way to use/pass cursor in the class. I'm working on small project where I will have couple of classes. I wan't each object of those classes have access to db. What option should I take?

Option 1

```
class Connector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

class SpamClassA(Connector):
    <body class>

class SpamClassB(Connector):
    <body class>
```

Option 2

```
class Connector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

class SpamClassA:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

class SpamClassB:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that the second option is not used by anyone.

Comment: Yes, but question is if I create thousends of SpamClassA or SpamClassB it wouldnt "slow down" connection? Each time will be created new connector object. In option 2 I can pass one and the same connector object to all SpamClassA/B objects

Comment: Is the `db_path ` the same database, or different databases?

Comment: The same database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider creating a singleton class (as it's the same database that is used). You would only have a single connection, which would close when the instance is deleted. It will be suitable for use with Option 1.

```py
class Connection:
    _conn = None

    def __init__(self, db_path):
        if self._conn is None:
            self._conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        self.cursor = self._conn.cursor()

    def __del__(self):
        if self._conn is not None:
            self._conn.close()
            self._conn = None
```

Comment: I like this solution :). I forgotten about singletons (shame on me).THANKS !
P.S.
I can't vote since my reputation is below 15 :(

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: I feel like it's most concise and would take less time to process. Option 2 is a bit of an old and roundabout way of doing things.